# How can I scroll in android/ios from top to bottom using appium driver?

Tags: java, android, ios, appium

1. I want to scroll an android mobile app page from top to bottom.
2. I have tried with below defined coding for scroll and click for specific web element using text. It works fine.

   // method 1
       driver.scrollTo("R");

   // method 2
     driver.ScrollToExact("Top");
3. But I need to swipe an full article page from top to bottom, without using above scroll() methods. I have tried with below coding, but scroll action doesn't happens for me.
   // scroll to bottom of an page
4. ((JavascriptExecutor) driver) .executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,
   document.body.scrollHeight)"); 
   How can I scroll an android app page from top to bottom using appium driver?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
page.swipe(SwipeElementDirection.UP, 400)
```

you can use it in loop, if you want.

Comment: I can able to scroll down to page  only two times by using above command. why?

Comment: Try to change duration from 400 to i.e. 1000. Slower swipe will maybe work better.

Answer (score 0):

An easy and intuitive way it to use Appium inspector,
you select swipe and then press a start point and an end point.
and it will generate the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
AndroidElement listView = (AndroidElement) wd.findElementByClassName("android.widget.ScrollView");

List<MobileElement> textView = wd.findElementsByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text(\"Top\")");

while (textView.size() == 0) {

System.out.println("Size : " + textView.size());

listView.swipe(SwipeElementDirection.UP, 20, 15, 5000);

textView = wd.findElementsByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text(\"Top\")");

}
```